# Return registry key value to copy files to directory

Tags: vbscript

Does anyone know hoe to return the value of a registry key of which I know the location of the key so that I can use it to copy a file to the installed directory? I know where the registry key is that contains the installed path of the program and wish to copy a file to the installed directory without knowing the install directory other than returning it from the registry. Am trying to do this in vbscript

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156602.aspx Note that to read from HKLM elevation is required

Comment: @AlexK. Reading from HKLM does not require elevation as long as the ACLs grant read access to normal users. Which they do for most of HKLM.